# Iterate over a list to apply a method to each member

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I have a list of strings that I want to apply a method (`.split`). I know this can be done by a `for` loop but knowing the mentality of python I assume there is a better way, like the `map` function

Below is the thing I want written using `for` loop

```
config = ['a b', 'c d']

configSplit = [None] * len(config)
for x in range(len(config)):
    configSplit[x] = config[x].split()

configSplit
> [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like this

```
>>> config = ['a b','c d']
>>> [item.split() for item in config]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

If you want to use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), you can pass [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function to it. But, Python 3.x's `map` returns an iterable map object.

```
>>> map(str.split, config)
<map object at 0x7f9843a64a90>
```

So, you need to explicitly convert that to a list, with the [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function, like this

```
>>> list(map(str.split, config))
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to anwser by @thefourtheye you can use `map`:

```
config = ['a b','c d']

new_config = list(map(lambda x: x.split(), config))

print(new_config)
# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Comment: Nope, `lambda` is not necessary. You can directly pass `str.split` like in my answer.

Comment: @thefourtheye yep, you right. But as more general case, its good to know about lambda if some other operation on the input list is required.

Comment: In Python 2 `str.split()` is going to be more specific and won't work on unicode strings. Better to use `string.split`, or use `lambda` as per this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
config = ['a b','c d']
```

Create an empty list

```
configSplit = list()
```

Iterate over each item, split, add to new list.

```
for item in config:
    configSplit.append(item.split())
```